# Should I deep copy when modifying nested object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I recently started learning functional programming in Javascript, and one thing that's valued is Immutability. One way to preserve immutability is to when we want to modify some object that we first create a copy and then modify that copy and return it, for example:

```js
const person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
}

const modifyFName = obj => {
    const objCopy = {...obj};
    objCopy.firstName = 'James';
    return objCopy;
}

console.log(modifyFName(person)) // {firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith'}
console.log(person) // {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}
```

But if I want to modify some deeply nested object creating shallow copy like one above wouldn't make much of a difference, for example:

```js
const person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    parents: {
        mom: {
            firstName: 'Jennifer',
            lastName: "Swift"
        },
        dad: {
            firstName: 'Tom',
            lastName: 'Cartman'
        }
    }
}

const modifyDadName = obj => {
    const objCopy = {...obj};
    objCopy.parents.dad.firstName = 'Aurelion';
    return objCopy;
}

console.log(modifyDadName(person)) // {... dad: "Aurelion"}
console.log(person) // {... dad: "Aurelion"}
```

Both objects have changed. So I am wondering in this situation should I perhaps use deep copy, or maybe use some third-party Immutable data structures, or is there some other solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that a shallow copy doesn't help, but you don't need a **full** deep copy, you only have to make copies of the things you want to change. In your case, that's `person`, `parents`, and `dad`, but not `mom`:

```
const modifyDadName = obj => {
    return {                            // Replacement `obj` (`person`)
        ...obj,
        parents: {                      // Replacement `obj.parents`
            ...obj.parents,
            dad: {                      // Replacement `obj.parents.dad`
                ...obj.parents.dad,
                firstName: "Aurelion",  // New name
            }
        }
    };
};
```

`dad` changes because, well, that's the operation we're doing (changing `firstName`). :-) `parents` changes because changing `dad` means there's a new object on its `dad` property. `person` (`obj`) changes because there's a new `parents` object. But `mom` doesn't change, so we can reuse the same object.